# Number of combinations given range

Tags: python, algorithm

Say you are given a range of numbers,
`[1,2,3]` where `r = 3`

and you are required to find the number of combinations of numbers that can be formed given a min and max group size. For example,

```
min = 1
max = 3
```

Can have the following configurations:

```
Config 1: [1, 2, 3]  
Config 2: [1, 2] [3] 
Config 3: [1, 3] [2] 
Config 4: [2, 3] [1] 
Config 5: [1] [2, 3] 
Config 6: [2] [1, 3] 
Config 7: [3] [1, 2] 
Config 8: [1] [2] [3] 
Config 9: [1] [3] [2] 
Config 10: [2] [1] [3] 
Config 11: [2] [3] [1] 
Config 12: [3] [1] [2] 
Config 13: [3] [2] [1]
```

The order matters: [1] [2] is different from [2] [1], but
[1, 2] is the same as [2, 1]

More examples:

```
r = 7, min = 2, max = 7
```

will yield 1730

```
r = 7, min = 2, max = 3
```

will yield 1400 as

```
[1,2,3], [4,5,6] 3 3 = ncr(7,3) * ncr(4, 3) = 140
[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7] 3 2 2 = ncr(7,3) * ncr(4, 2) * 3 = 630
[1,2], [3,4], [5,6] 2 2 2 = ncr(7,2) * ncr(5, 2) * ncr(3, 2) = 630
```

```
r = 7, min = 2, max = 2
```

will yield 630 as

```
(ncr(7,2) * ncr(5, 2) * ncr(3,2)) = 630
```

This gets progressively more difficult as the numbers get larger. The question is, how do i write a function that takes in r, a, b that is able to give me the number of different configurations? I cannot wrap my head around the combinations and permutations for this.

Edit: Added in more examples and made question more specific for the end goal

Comment: Have you looked at the [`itertools` utilities](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for this?

Comment: @AKX Hi, can you be a little more specific? I am aware combinations and permutations are involved but not so much on the implementation of a generic function that can cover these cases.

Comment: Just figured there'd be a tool you could use there. Anyway: why isn't e.g. `[3, 2, 1]` or `[2, 1, 3]`, etc. a configuration? Looks like the internal ordering of the groups doesn't matter, so they'd be sets...?

Comment: Yep, [1] [2] is different from [2] [1], but  [1, 2] is the same as [2, 1]. Ill edit the question to be more specific

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you already have a function```ncr``` (which should be the binomial coefficient) or are you looking for a function to do that? In that case, it would be ```scipy.special.binom```.

Comment: @BernieD I am looking for a function that is able to give me the number of different configurations given r (the range(1,r+1), 1 to r inclusive), a (the minimum number of elements in a group) and b (the max num of elements in a group). I already have implementations of the functions for combination and permutation (or itertools provided otherwise as AKX stated)

Comment: In your example with `r=7, min=max=2`, you can throw out an element to produce combinations using only 6 elements. Why can't you do that in your first example with `r=3, min=1, max=3`, for example have `[1,2]` without the `[3]` be a configuration (separate from `[1,2][3]` and `[3][1,2]`)?

Comment: @Nelfeal my interpretation is that the configuration has to be maximal in the sense of not being able to add another group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm skeptical that, with three parameters, there's a nice closed form, but the memoized recursive function below should do the trick.

```
import functools
import math


@functools.cache
def count(r, min, max):
    if r < 0:
        return 0
    if r < min:
        return 1
    return sum(math.comb(r, k) * count(r - k, min, max) for k in range(min, max + 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def test(r, min, max):
        print("X={}, Y={}, Z={} --> {}".format(r, min, max, count(r, min, max)))

    test(3, 1, 3)
    test(7, 2, 7)
    test(7, 2, 3)
    test(7, 2, 2)
```

Output:

```
X=3, Y=1, Z=3 --> 13
X=7, Y=2, Z=7 --> 1730
X=7, Y=2, Z=3 --> 1400
X=7, Y=2, Z=2 --> 630
```

Comment: This works! Thank you!! Just a small plus is to add a ```if k <= r``` to account for the cases where ```r - k``` returns a negative number, like in the case of ```r = 7, min = 3, ma x= 6```